# Agrupar columnas en una sola columna SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo los siguientes datos:

```
SELECT * 
FROM AR_MESES_TOTALES
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De que manera puedo mostrar las cantidades de los meses en una sola columna y en otra columna indicar a que mes pertenecen las cantidades

Comment: Y cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Saludos. Mejora tu planteamiento, solo pusiste que tienes; ahora falta ilustres que resultado quieres obtener así como lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto existe el operador Unpivot. Básicamente es convertir en filas, lo que tienes en columnas

```
CREATE TABLE AR_MESES_TOTALES (
ID_SEGMENTO INT, 
SEGMENTO VARCHAR(100), 
ESTATUS VARCHAR(100), 
CONCEPTO VARCHAR(100), 
[ENE-20] DECIMAL(10,2),
[FEB-20] DECIMAL(10,2),
[MAR-20] DECIMAL(10,2),
[ABR-20] DECIMAL(10,2),
[MAY-20] DECIMAL(10,2),
[JUN-20] DECIMAL(10,2),
[JUL-20] DECIMAL(10,2),
[AGO-20] DECIMAL(10,2),
[SEP-20] DECIMAL(10,2),
[OCT-20] DECIMAL(10,2),
[NOV-20] DECIMAL(10,2),
[DIC-20] DECIMAL(10,2)
);
GO
INSERT INTO AR_MESES_TOTALES 
(ID_SEGMENTO, SEGMENTO, ESTATUS, CONCEPTO, 
[ENE-20], [FEB-20], [MAR-20], [ABR-20], 
[MAY-20], [JUN-20], [JUL-20], [AGO-20], 
[SEP-20], [OCT-20], [NOV-20], [DIC-20])
VALUES
( 9901,'Pyme','ADMINISTRATIVA','Daciones'
 ,0,0,0,0
 ,0,0,0,0
 ,0,0,0,0
),
( 9901,'Pyme','ADMINISTRATIVA','Efectivo'
 ,52790.49,50200.19,51491.54,51209.3
 ,48272.32,50386.83,48991.98,52397.36
 ,55661.61,54198.16,55942.53,56361.67
),
( 9901,'Pyme','ADMINISTRATIVA','Reestructura'
 ,10327.57,5402.26,10577.13,11433.86
 ,10587.53,10855.89,10368.74,10893.37
 ,11367.4,10872.81,11024.32,10910.53
),
( 9901,'Pyme','ADMINISTRATIVA','Saldo Gestionable'
 ,112498.04,118151.3,109512.24,117672.29
 ,108308.4,110387.43,104801.19,109443.31
 ,113520.47,107929.85,108777.17,107008.45
);

GO

SELECT p.ID_SEGMENTO
     , p.SEGMENTO
     , p.ESTATUS
     , p.CONCEPTO
     , p.CANTIDAD
     , p.MESES
       FROM (
              SELECT *
                     FROM AR_MESES_TOTALES 
            ) AS SOURCE UNPIVOT(CANTIDAD FOR MESES IN([ENE-20]
                                                    , [FEB-20]
                                                    , [MAR-20]
                                                    , [ABR-20]
                                                    , [MAY-20]
                                                    , [JUN-20]
                                                    , [JUL-20]
                                                    , [AGO-20]
                                                    , [SEP-20]
                                                    , [OCT-20]
                                                    , [NOV-20]
                                                    , [DIC-20])
            ) P;
```

Si observas la consulta, en la tabla derivada llamada source, estableces el origen de los datos. Luego aplicas el operador unpivot y estableces el "importe" para el "nombre" de la columna.

[image: Resultado]

[Unpivot](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizando la opcion PIVOT/UNPIVOT de SQL. Ten en cuenta que el guion te dara problemas (podría confundirse con menos en las consultas), por lo que en el codigo que he puesto abajo, lo he omitido.

```
SELECT ID_SEGMENTO, SEGMENTO, ESTATUS, CONCEPTO, MESES, MONTO
FROM (SELECT ID_SEGMENTO, SEGMENTO, ESTATUS, CONCEPTO, ENE20, FEB20,
             MAR20, ABR20, MAY20, JUN20, JUL20, AGO20, SEP20, OCT20,
             NOV20, DIC20 FROM  AR_MESES_TOTALES) mt
UNPIVOT
(MONTO FOR MESES IN
    (ENE20, FEB20, MAR20, ABR20, MAY20, JUN20, JUL20, AGO20, SEP20, OCT20, NOV20, DIC20))
    AS unpvt;
```